# AngularJS: Custom directive using dynamic attribute value doesn't work inside "ng-repeat"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Could you explain please why the following directive doesn't work?

`attrs.ngMydirective` seems to be `undefined` inside the linking function.

[Live example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/o5OTuV?p=preview)

HTML:

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in people">
      {{ person.name }}
      <span ng-mydirective="{{ person.age }}"></span>  
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('ngMydirective', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (parseInt(attrs.ngMydirective, 10) < 18) {
        element.html('child'); 
      }
    }
  };
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.people = [
    {name: 'John', age: 33},
    {name: 'Michelle', age: 5}
  ];
});
```

Comment: for any1 looking here my problem was the uppercases in the directive decleration. for some reason changing myDirective to mydirective made it work. i am using dot net SP2013 and wrote uppercase in the ascx, the change was in the JS

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should use `attrs.$observe` to have actual value.

Another approach is to pass this value to directive's scope and `$watch` it.

Both approaches are shown here ([live example](http://plnkr.co/edit/58OCBM?p=preview)):

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.directive('ngMydirective', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$observe('ngMydirective', function(value) {
        if (parseInt(value, 10) < 18) {
          element.html('child'); 
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
app.directive('ngMydirective2', function() {
  return {
    replace: true,
    scope: { ngMydirective2: '@' },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('ngMydirective2', function(value) {
        console.log(value);
        if (parseInt(value, 10) < 18) {
          element.html('child'); 
        }
      });
    }
  };
});

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.people = [
    {name: 'John', age: 33},
    {name: 'Michelle', age: 5}
  ];
});
```

```html
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in people">
      {{ person.name }}
      <span ng-mydirective="{{ person.age }}"></span>  
    </li>
    <li ng-repeat="person in people">
      {{ person.name }}
      <span ng-mydirective2="{{ person.age }}"></span>  
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
```